# How to pass an single input element out of 3 input element into component in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a component that renders 3 input fields, out of which I need to show a single element in first-line and the other two in different lines

for ex 1.
firstStep: phoneNumber

secondStep: areaCode, city

ExistinguserInfo.js component:

```
export const ExistinguserInfo = () => {
//some onchange code and props
 return(
 myfield.Input
    id="q-phonenumber"
    label="Phone number"
    value={PhNumber}
    maxLength={10}
  />
 myfield.Input
    id="q-areaCode"
    label="areaCode"
    value={areaCode}
    maxLength={10}
  />
myfield.Input
    id="q-city"
    label="City"
    value={city}
    maxLength={10}
  />
}
```

userinfo.js

```
export const userInfor = () => {
  //someCode
   const step1 = () => {
return {
  title: 'phonenumber',
  body: (
    <ExistinguserInfo/>
     //**I need only PhoneFiled**
  )  
}
}
const step2 = () => {
return {
  title: 'Areacode && City',
  body: (
    <ExistinguserInfo/>
     //**I need AreaCode and city field**
  ),
}


    OR
```

Do I need to create a separate component for displaying phoneNumber not sure

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it so complicated. Simply use the composition feature of React.

Create a single component like this.

```js
const ExistinguserInfo = (id, label, value, maxLength) => {
   return(
    myfield.Input
      id={id}
      label={label}
      value={value}
      maxLength={maxLength}
    />
  )
}
```

Then call that with necessary props.

```js
export const userInfor = () => {
  const step1 = () => {
    return {
      title: "phonenumber",
      body: (
        <ExistinguserInfo
          id="q-phonenumber"
          label="Phone number"
          value={PhNumber}
          maxLength={10}
        />
        //**I need only PhoneFiled**
      )
    };
  };

  const step2 = () => {
    return {
      title: "Areacode && City",
      body: (
        <ExistinguserInfo
          id="q-areaCode"
          label="areaCode"
          value={areaCode}
          maxLength={10}
        />
        <ExistinguserInfo
          id="q-city"
          label="City"
          value={city}
          maxLength={10}
        />
        //**I need AreaCode and city field**
      )
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks Yushan, Can't we go with the same format??

Comment: You can but it's not suitable in React. There are certain best practices in the industry. We always have to try to follow them.